# How to add root directory in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I add a document to the root directory of an Eclipse project? I need to add the design of my Java project, but I can't have it stored in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to copy the document with `Ctrl+C` (you can copy the file either from Eclipse or your OS), then go to Eclipse and in the Project Explorer window do the following:

- Select the project name (root directory) you wish to copy the file to.
- Right click on that name and select `Paste` or alternatively use `Ctrl+V` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, under your project on the left hand side of the IDE their should be a window called 'Project Explorer', if its not there have a look at https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm

Once you can see it, click on your project which you can directly copy and paste to from you file explorer.